# Burst images will not upload when sharing to iCloud via iPhoto

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app, photo-stream, macos

I took burst photos with my iPhone 6.  Plugged into iMac, iPhoto opens, I pull all the images off my phone and into a new iPhoto event, they are no longer on my phone.  Now I want to share them using iPhoto -> Share -> iCloud -> New photo stream.  When I do this only the non-burst images get uploaded.  Why?  I want them all.  I do not have Photo Stream turned on.  I don't know if that matters.  I don't want it on.

I am running the latest version of OS X Yosemite & iPhoto 9.5.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you take photos with burst mode or image stabilization on your iPhone 5s, only the photos you select as favorites when using burst mode and the final composite image shot with image stabilization are added to My Photo Stream.

If you want all burst-mode photos uploaded to My Photo Stream and your iPhone has iOS 7.1 or later, go to Settings > Photos & Camera and turn on Upload Burst Photos.

Source: [iCloud: My Photo Stream overview](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13692?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)